# How many Planck times would there be from the Big Bang to the Big Rip?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, time, big-bang, estimation

How many Planck times would there be from the Big Bang to the [Big Rip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip)? (approx.) Does this number have any numerical significance to mathematics?

If you had a CPU clock which had a timer counting from the big bang. How many bits would the CPU have to be?

If you took the number of 4 dimensional plank volumes from the big bang to the big rip bounded by the visible universe at any time. (which would give a double-cone shape.) What number is this? How many bits for a CPU need to express this number.

I'm just thinking about how what the maximum number of bits an immortal computer would need and not run into any Y2K problems!

Comment: When is the 'big rip'?

Comment: The end of the Universe

Comment: When is the end of the Universe?

Comment: @zooby +1 explained: this question might not be all on the hard-core side of physics, but it's absolutely at the heart of why we even have physics, the nature of it embodies the true spirit of physics; too bad I couldn't give it +2.

Answer (score 1):

Googling rather than calculating, I see it asserted that the age of the universe is about 10^60 Planck times, and that the size of the observable universe is above 10^180 Planck volumes. As for a big rip, it could happen any time from tomorrow to a googolplex years in the future to never. So maybe you can set a crude lower bound on the number of "Planck hypervolumes" needed so far, as about 10^240, or about 2^800.

Comment: Interesting. So I think one might use a 512 or 1024-bit computer.